# Least common multiple without using gcd

Tags: haskell

With gcd its fairly easy but i do not understand how to tie in all the functions to make it happen without.

```
kgv :: Int -> Int -> Int
kgv x y =  abs ((x `quot` (gcd x y)) * y)
```

I got this function to find the prime factors which works (`prime_factors`) and I am working on making a function that takes the maximum number from one list and checks if its on the other list (`comp`):

```
prime_factors :: Int -> [Int]
prime_factors 1 = []
prime_factors n
  | factors == []  = [n]
  | otherwise = factors ++ prime_factors (n `div` (head factors))
  where factors = take 1 $ filter (\x -> (n `mod` x) == 0) [2 .. n-1]


comp :: [Int]->Int
comp (ys)(x:xs)
 |maximum prime_factors xs elem prime_factors ys == x
 |otherwise tail x


kgv :: Int -> Int -> Int
kgv x y =  abs ((x `quot` (comp x y)) * y)
```

Comment: Have you heard of the Euclidean algorithm? That will be much better than any technique based on prime factorization.

Comment: it sounds like multiplication

Comment: the euclidean algorithm **is** a way to get the gcd - so if you want to do it without (why?) then this is not the way

Comment: if you want you can do the *naive* algorithm: take the multiples of your numbers (always increase the smaller) till you get to the point where both numbers are equal - this is a simple recursive algorithm you should be able to figure out

Comment: @Carsten, perhaps I misunderstood the intention. I figured they just weren't allowed to use a pre-existing gcd function. Doing without that seems more a question for math.stackexchange.com than for this site.

Comment: @dfeuer the best Haskell/Programming exercises always are ;) ... of course chances are high that I totally got this wrong and you are right ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an absurdly simple and obscenely inefficient solution:

```
lcm m n = head [x | x <- [1..], x `rem` m == 0, x `rem` n == 0]
```

Of course, this relies on two different notions of "least" coinciding under the circumstances, which they do. A fully naive solution doesn't seem possible.

Comment: or, `lcm m n = head [x | x <- [n,2*n..], rem x m == 0]`

Comment: @karakfa, sure, that's perfectly valid as well. Since neither of them is remotely close to being efficient, I figured it best to go for the very simplest.

Answer (score 3):

here is the (very) *naive* algorithm I was talking about:

```
kgv :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
kgv x y = find x y
  where find i j
          | i == j = i
          | i < j = find (i+x) j
          | i > j = find i (j+y)
```

it's basically what a school-child would do ;)

---

**caution** I ignored negative numbers and 0 - you'll probably have to handle those

Answer (score 3):

perhaps another easy way is

```
import Data.List(intersect)
lcm m n = head $ intersect (series m n) (series n m)     
    where series a b = take a $ map (*b) [1..]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself mostly. Thanks for the ideas and pointers.

```
ggt n m   | n > m     = maximum [t | t <- [1 .. m], gt n m t]
    | otherwise = maximum [t | t <- [1 .. n], gt n m t]
gt n m c              = t n c  && t m c
t n c     | n >= c    = (mod n c == 0)
    | otherwise = False

kgv :: Int -> Int -> Int
kgv x y |x==0=0|y==0=0 |otherwise = abs ((x `quot` (ggt x y)) * y)
```